# Nginx - Mediawiki - Limit access to the connexion page to specified ip

Tags: nginx, ip, mediawiki

I would like to limit the possibility to connect to my Mediawiki web site to a specified list of ip.
The url to connect are :

- /index.php/Spécial:Connexion
- /index.php?title=Spécial:Connexion
- /index.php?title=Spécial:Connexion&action=submitlogin&type=login

I use Nginx.
My first thought was to limit the acces to /index.php/Spécial:Connexion

```
location = /index.php/Spécial:Connexion {
    allow   127.0.0.1;
    deny    all;
}
```

And for the other, I thought to do this

```
location = /index.php {
    if ($arg_title = "Sp%C3%A9cial:Connexion")
    {
        # allow / deny are not allowed in an if statement 
    }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea to achieve my goal ?

Comment: What's so special about Spécial:Connexion? I deduce that you're talking of a private wiki, entirely or partly restricted to logged in users, but you are the only logged in user, hence you want to restrict access to Special:userlogin. Is this correct? What *are* logged out users supposed to see?

Comment: Exactly, the whole content of the wiki is accessible to everyone, but I am the only one which can edit the content. I would like to restrict the access Spécial:Connexion to myself.